# Разметка. Вывод данных в виде таблицы

Tags: html, php, разметка

Доброй ночи.
Возник вопрос с разметкой. Из некоторой таблицы бд выводятся данные, мне нужно чтобы выведенные данные отображались в виде 2х колонок.
Что-то вроде такого:

```
   Колонка 1             Колонка 2
    сслыка                ссылка
    ссылка                ссылка
    .....                 .....
```

Вывод из БД

```
while($url=$sql->fetch($sql->query("SELECT `url`,`name` FROM `category` WHERE `id_cat` = $cat ")))
 {
  /* здесь и возник вопрос как сделать 2 колонки. причем если 2 ссылки то они в строку,
 если 3, то 2 в строку, 3я переносится под 1ю и т.д */
  ???
 }
```

Comment: while($url=$sql->fetch($sql->query("SELECT `url`,`name` FROM `category` WHERE `id_cat` = $cat ")))

    // 'while true' detected

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
echo '<table>';
$n = 0;
$q = $sql->query("SELECT `url`,`name` FROM `category` WHERE `id_cat` = $cat ");
while($url=$sql->fetch($q)) {
  if (!($n % 2)) echo '<tr>';
  echo '<td>'.$url->someData.'</td>';
  if ($n % 2) echo '</tr>';
  $n++;
}
if ($n % 2) echo '<td></td></tr>';
echo '</table>';
```

Comment: это только +

Comment: Спасибо! Все работает:)

Comment: Ябы всё-же оперировал флагом...

    echo '<table>';
    $f = false;
    $q = $sql->query("SELECT `url`,`name` FROM `category` WHERE `id_cat` = $cat ");
    while( $url=$sql->fetch($q) ) {
      echo ( !$f ? '<tr>' : '' ).'<td>'.$url->someData.'</td>'.( $f ? '</tr>' : '' );
      $f = !$f;
    }
    if ($f) echo '<td></td></tr>';
    echo '</table>';